# insert values from user using openpyxl in python?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using python 3.10. My project is to generate excel sheets taking the input from the user and store it in my local device. So, how can i store with the user input? i heard about openpyxl but it did not work for me

Comment: Where do you want to store the user input? In an excel sheet? In a text file? Please show us your code and tell us in what way your code doesn't work.

Comment: I want to store the user input in the excel sheet where will be stored in my local device, i post the code

Comment: Please include your own code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import openpyxl

wb =  openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet(title = "sheet1")  # for creating a new sheet 
val=int(input("Enter the value ->"))    # user input 
ws['A5']=val                           # A5 cell address & val is the user 
input wb.save("new.xlsx")
```

This code will work